# how can I make a style sheet for all IE browsers. Not just IE 8 in ie.css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, stylesheet, ie7.js

How can I make a style sheet for all IE browsers. Not just IE 8 in ie.css

in the ie.css file the theme of this website includes only IE8 styles.

Comment: you need to detect IE or IE feature, then render ie.css if found.

Comment: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they did that was because they likely do not support Internet Explorer 7. And Internet Explorer 8 has a lot of quirks that 9 does not. So that stylesheet might have been created specifically to address those bugs.

Also you might be finding that stylesheet because you are accessing it from IE8 and there was a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to serve you styles specific to you.

Usually IE is an afterthought after various users complain. Then the web developer on that project creates a quickfix for it. And they just add that stylesheet rather than modifying the main stylesheet.

In my case, I have support down to IE7. I just have all styles in the same sheet. But this is more feasible for me since I code with IE7 in mind from the beginning. Also less to worry about when you are using something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

## tldr

Just put it in the same file. Or even add them to your main stylesheet if you have a small set of rules.